# Subversion action in NetBeans module

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, module, platform

I'm developing a NetBeans module that periodically checks SVN for project commits. I would like to automaticaly update that project without using the mouse, only by the code in that module. I tried to search some tips how to use Subversion API without creating my own popup within the project but I didn't find anything.

Is there any way to update a specified project from SVN using just code?

Thanks for advice if there is some.

Answer (score 0):

Get a look at these java API's for subversion:

- [svnClientAdapter](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnClientAdapter.html)
- [svnkit](http://svnkit.com/)